Making signature immune to Colliding Signatures and other threats
Some signature schemes1 have strong Existential UnForgeability under Chosen Message Attack (sEUF-CMA), but still allow Colliding Signatures or/and fail to provide Conservative or/and Destructive Exclusive Ownership (CEO/DEO). These additional threats and security properties are defined by Dennis Jackson, Cas Cremers, Katriel Cohn-Gordon and Ralf Sasse's Seems Legit: Automated Analysis of Subtle Attacks on Protocols that Use Signatures (originally in proceedings of CCS 2019).
Can we devise a generic method to add these properties (resistance to Colliding Signatures, CEO and DEO) to a sEUF-CMA signature scheme (with appendix), without increasing the signature size, and with little increase in computational cost?
Would this generic method work? Define a block cipher $E$ (modeled as a keyed PRP or Ideal Cipher) with message space the same as the signature, and an auxiliary hash function $H'$ (modeled as a PRF or Random Oracle, wide enough for collision resistance) over the key space of the block cipher. After signature production, replace $S$ with $S'=E_{H'(\mathrm{Pub}\mathbin\|M)}(S)$. At verification, replace $S'$ with $S=E^{-1}_{H'(\mathrm{Pub}\mathbin\|M)}(S')$ before applying the verification algorithm.
If so, how simple can $E$ (and $H'$) be? In particular, can we use some rounds of Feistel and a XOF like SHAKE to build the round functions and $H'$?

Update following this comment: CEO/DEO, and how to add these security properties, is investigated by Thomas Pornin and Julien P. Stern in Digital Signatures Do Not Guarantee Exclusive Ownership, in proceedings of ACNS 2005. However they do not consider the threat of colliding signature, and their proposed constructions do not work against that threat in the motivating example below.

1 A motivating example is the original short Schnorr signature, when instantiated with 128-bit hash, and a Schnorr group with 256-bit prime $q$ (group size) and 3072-bit prime $p$. That's sEUF-CMA, but still one can sign a message and later produce a message of different meaning that verifies against the original signature. The attack works with a non-maliciously generated key pair and without compromising the secrecy of the private key. This can be viewed as a repudiation risk. And at least, we must not use a signature as a commitment of the message.
The attack works by creating a collision in the 128-bit hashes $H(r\mathbin\|M_0)=H(r\mathbin\|M_1)$ where $r$ is chosen the normal way by the signer. This only requires the ability to choose about 9 bytes in each of the two colliding messages $M_0$ and $M_1$, and about $2^{66}$ hash operations, that can be efficiently distributed.

I didn't look closely at the proposed construction, I think such constructions may exist in the litterature. The original Pornin-Stern paper gave some solutions. Including signing both message and public key (unambiguously encoded). Or a hash thereof. If signature size cam increase, the BUFF construction has additional properties.

@MarcIlunga: I welcome references to solutions in the literature, and added link to the Pornin-Stern paper in the question. However their solution does not discuss colliding signature, nor apply to the motivating example.

Another interesting question is also how simple can $H'$ be? There are some trivial examples that do not work, but do we have to fully rely on the ROM? Then again, I haven't fully thought through the question. : )

@fgrieu, you are right. I missed that the question asked for a construction providing several security notions, including collisions. I suppose the references I have targeted mostly "other threats." For completeness, here's a reference to the BUFF construction: https://ia.cr/2020/1525.

this is mostly for me, but could you expand on your estimates for the complexity of breaking the motivating example? Is $H$ modelled as an RO?

I thought more about this: the proposed solution is insufficient because security can not simply rely on PRP security. I'll write a partial answer later. But the intuitive reason is that we can exhibit a PRP $E'$ (function of $(E, m, m', Pub)$, so collisions are guaranteed with an overwhelming advantage. The intuition is that we can rig the PRP and move around pre-image pairs to create collision under different keys. But changing a single evaluation result doesn't change the PRP security of $E'$ (just as good as $E$). Of course, this is not possible for arbitrary block ciphers.

My intuition is that the collision resistance of signatures can't be better than the collision resistance of the hash function on the input space. All of the degrees of freedom in the inputs (message, key, associated data) will always allow for adversarial probing of the output space of the hash function for favorable collisions. I think the only viable generic solution would be to increase the hash output size to increase the difficulty of finding collisions.

@aiootp: I agree. That's why I add an auxiliary collision-resistant hash function $H'$. In practice, we'd use the strategy in Ed25519ph: compute a strong prehash of the message, and feed that instead of the message $M$ to both the original signature scheme's hash $H$ (too narrow to avoid collision), and the auxiliary hash $H'$.

That's sound. But that wouldn't apply to the motivating example involving 128-bit hashes, right? ...Another thought, which is not actually generic, is that bijective permutations could be helpful when the inputs are severely restricted. Such as, fixed or blocksize length messages, and static or out-of-band committed to associated data. Maybe something could be constructed without collisions in that case, but as long as the signing key isn't committed to a priori, the degrees of freedom in the key itself would be enough to void that potential.

@aiootp: I think the technique works with the motivating example. The 128-bit $H$ is enough to prevent forgery, while the $H'$ and $E$ prevent colliding signature and signature appropriation with a different public key. At least that's the intent.

This is only a partial answer. It mostly addresses the fact that the proposed solution doesn't work generically. This is done by exhibiting secure schemes so that their composition in the proposed isn't secure. To be clear, the claim is about the generic security of the scheme, which is a requirement of the question. It is, in fact, very possible that the proposed construction is practically secure for specific instantiations. Like there are secure instantiations of Mac-then-Encrypt, e.g., CCM, next, I'll describe an alternative that potentially side-steps the previously mentioned issue. However, I have no proof that the alternative works generically, and it may potentially fail to some due to some other subtleties. I'll also discuss existing solutions that partially answer the requirements: they provide the required security guarantees at negligible computational costs but increase the signature size (by a hash), or they do not increase signature size but are not generic.
Context: The notion of “Collision resistance for signature” for signature, as described in the question, is also referred to in the literature as “Message Binding” (Boneh-Shoup, Brendel et al., Cremers et al..)
Generic security of the proposed solution
Assuming the reasoning below is not flawed, the solution suggested in the question does not appear to work generically, which is a question requirement. To do so, for any signature scheme $\Sigma = (\text{KGen}, \text{Sig}, \text{Vrfy})$ we will devise a secure PRP $E'_{\Sigma}$ so that breaking MBS security of the generic construction is easy. Which contradicts the generic security of the construction solely based on PRP security.
As a starting point, one question is what properties $E$ and $H'$ should have. Below are some observations, not to be interpreted as attacks but
as potential difficulties proving the security of the proposed construction.
Starting with $H'$. it must at least be collision-resistant. The trivial example where $H'(m) = 0, \forall m$ is a boring illustration of this. On the other hand, since the output of $H'$ is used to key a blockcipher, it seems necessary that $H'$ has some pseudo-random behavior and, therefore, is strictly more than collision-resistant. Alternatively, collision resistance could be enough if we accept working with the stronger ideal-cipher model (more on later).
Onto the PRP $E$: The first observation is that the PRP key is public, so it's unclear how to rely on PRP security. Secondly, it is possible that PRP security is not enough for the proposed solution to provide collision resistance generally. We can exhibit a PRP so that the construction fails to provide message-bound signature security (MBS). Details below.
Let $(m, m')$ be the message for which the attacker wants to create signature collisions under $pk$. We create another $E$, so the construction isn't secure. For simplicity, we consider a deterministic signing scheme, and we further define $\sigma_m$ and $\sigma_{m'}$ as signatures on $m$ and $m'$, respectively. Also, let $s$ and $s'$ be the block cipher output after applying the transformation(e.g.: $s = E_k(H'(pk|m), \sigma_m)$). We can now construct a new keyed PRP $E'$ that makes the construction insecure. $E'$ behaves just like $E$ and only with the only change that $$s = E'_k(H'(pk|m'), \sigma_{m'}),$$ and the original pre-image of $s'$ (say $v$) is mapped $E_k(H'(pk|m'), \sigma_{m'})$. In summary, we changed the following mappings under the key $H'(pk|m')$: $$(\sigma_{m'}, s'), (v,s) \to (\sigma_{m'}, s), (v,s')$$.
We observe that if $E$ was a secure PRP, then $E'$ is still a secure PRP. Namely, we haven't changed any guarantees expected from a PRP with a random key. However, the tuple $pk, m, m'$ breaks the MBS security of the generic construction. One thing to investigate is whether one could prove security in the ideal cipher model. Where for each key, each permutation behaves like a randomly chosen one... But I don't know...
Potential fix to the generic construction: TODO
The idea is to take inspiration from "re-encryption" type techniques. Concretely, the key to the PRP (permutation) is derived as a function of the public key, message, and signature $H'(pk,m,\sigma)$. Here, $H'$ is modeled as a random oracle with an image corresponding to the key space of the PRP. The rest goes as described in the question's proposal. Verification should verify the consistency of all values. Because of the “circular dependency” between the PRP key and input. It seems hard to play tricks on the PRP, as described above. However, this does not prove anything. Furthermore, I expect it to be hard to prove anything about this without employing ideal models.
Existing work: the BUFF construction.
Cremers et al. introduced a (collection of) security notions titled Beyond UnForgeability Features (BUFF). This captures Unforgeability, Malicious Stronger, MBS (collision resistance), and Non-assignability (NS). NS captures the inability to sign a message the adversary does not “know.” There are two generic transformations proposed $(\text{Sign}(sk, m), H(pk,m))$ and  $(\text{Sign}(sk, H(pk,m)), H(pk,m))$.
BUFF security appears to be a desirable feature of newer post-quantum schemes. Cremers et al. studied the BUFF security of round 3 NIST finalists, and newer candidates have also been analyzed by Aulbach et al..
On signature size: Both generic transforms inevitably increase signature size. However, for a specific scheme, the simpler transformation of Pornin and Stern, a.k.a PS-3, is shown to be enough to achieve BUFF security without increasing signature size. PS-3 is defined as $(\text{Sign}(sk, H(pk,m))$
Pornin-Stern transforms
Specifically for MBS security, the PS-1 transform provides MBS security (Collision resistance) under collision resistance of the hash function. PS-1 is defined as $(\text{Sign}(sk, n), H(m))$. However, the signature size must increase.
The picture below (from Cremers et al.) recaps the various constructions and their security.

